# Kotlin fun parameter passed to another function which is then returned

Tags: kotlin

Let's say we have the following 2 functions:

```
fun getStringOfNumber(number: Int): String {
    return number.toString()
}

fun printString(str: String) {
    println(str)
}
```

Then we call the following:

```
printString(5)
```

This will 100% not execute since we are passing `Int` into `String` parameter.

What I am looking to do is execute `getStringOfNumber` with `str`, then return that value in place of passed parameter to `printString` and then execute `println(str)` only this time with the value from `getStringOfNumber`.

I know this can be achieved in a bit different way but I would like this exact implementation, if it's possible of course.

Perhaps it would be easier to follow with this algorithm that I have in mind:

1. `printString` is called.
2. Before the body of the function is executed, the parameter passed is used to call `getStringOfNumber`
3. value returned from the `getStringOfNumber` is then stored as passed parameter.
4. body of the `printString` is now executed with new parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do this (without an annotation processor possibly) would be to overload the function.

```
fun printString(str: String) {
    println(str)
}

fun printString(num: Int) {
    printString(getStringOfNumber(num))
}
```

Comment: Yeah, somehow this didn't even strike me as a solution, but this definitely seems liek a way to go. Thanks a lot!